# When adding to a Rect is it dp?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a button that I want to have a bigger touch area.
To be specific the minHeight of the button should be 50dp but the height of the touch area should be 80 dp.
I am using the following code:

```
final Rect rect = new Rect();
rect.top += 15;
rect.bottom += 15;
button.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, button));
```

So my question is is the `rect.top += 15` done in dp?
I am not sure if this gives me `80dp` for height of the touch area (the `minWidth` of the `button` is set to `50dp` in the layout already)